# C++ Writing a file inside a loop

Tags: c++, file, loops, filestream, ofstream

This should be counting 30 seconds down into a txt file. But it hardly ever makes the txt itself either. What am I doing wrong? Or is it that in loop c++ is just not capable of file handling.
There is just nothing in the text file

```
for (i = 30; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        ofstream file;
        file.open("asd.txt");
        file << i;
        file.close();
        Sleep(1000);
    }
```

Comment: "But it hardly ever makes the txt itself either" What does that mean?

Comment: Are you saying that you're only getting `0` as the text inside the file? Well that's because you're not in append mode; add the openmode `std::ios_base::app` to `open`.

Comment: I want the txt to overwrite itself

Comment: Then what's the problem?

Comment: Your loop will run for ~31 seconds, not ~30.

Comment: And for hardly ever makes I mean sometimes it makes it sometimes not.

Comment: The problem is that it does not write anything to the txt file

Comment: Maybe you're looking at the wrong text file. Delete it and see if it gets recreated when you run your app.

Comment: If anything the text is not being flushed to the file after the write

Comment: @PeterM It gets flushed when the file is closed.

Comment: I thought it flushes by default but if not then ill try looking into that

Comment: @PeterM `close()` will flush internally.

Comment: My mistake about the flush, so used to other languages where it doesn't flush

Comment: @PeterM: Every language flushes on close. Every language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the ofstream out of the loop like this :

```
// ^^ There is the useless stuff
ofstream file;
for (i=0;i<maxs;i++)
{
    system("cls");
    secondsLeft=maxs-i;
    hours=secondsLeft/3600;
    secondsLeft=secondsLeft-hours*3600;
    minutes=secondsLeft/60;
    secondsLeft=secondsLeft-minutes*60;
    seconds=secondsLeft;
    cout << hours<< " : " << minutes<< " : " << seconds << " ";
    file.open ("countdown.txt", ios::trunc);
    file << hours << " : "  << minutes<< " : " << seconds;
    file.close();
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Basically what you do you create object which represents the file every time and you try to open it.
If you access the file every time with new reference(object) it writes new data and deletes previous data.
Try to do this:

```
int main()
{
    ofstream file;
    file.open("test.txt");
    for (int i = 30; i > 0; --i)
    {
        file << i << endl;
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    file.close();


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare `ofstream` out of loop.

If you have to use it inside loop, use append mode.

```
file.open("test.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you are overwriting your output file "asd.txt" with every loop.  You only need to create and initialize a file pointer once for each session you will do IO (outside of the loop).  The same goes for closing the file pointer.

```
ofstream file;    //Create file pointer variable
file.open("asd.txt");    //Initialize 'file" to open "asd.txt" for writing
for (i = 30; i >= 0; i--)
  {
   file << i;   //You'll need to add a new line if you want 1 number per line
   Sleep(1000);  //Assuming this is in microseconds so sleep for 1 second
  }
file.close();   //close the file pointer and flushing all pending IO operations to it.
```